# How is it possible to get 51 groups in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-groups

The [FAQ says](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/190/~/general-limits-for-linkedin-groups):

> How many subgroups can I be a member of at one time? 50.

How is it possible to get 51 groups?

[image]

https://www.linkedin.com/anet?dispSortAnets=&trk=my_groups-h_gn-settings :

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Is your limit 50?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually possible to join up to 100 groups on LinkedIn, according to [this post](https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140709191649-33513292-want-to-join-up-to-100-linkedin-groups) from someone who has joined 55 groups.  She explains in a video in her post that you can join 50 parent groups and 50 subgroups.  I checked a few of the groups in your screenshot, and I found that the "Disruptive I.T." group is actually a subgroup of the "Re-invent I.T." group.  You are a member of both groups, and since "Disruptive I.T." is a subgroup, that is how you are a member of more than 50 groups.

Comment: Wow good catch! What a mess this group system is.